# tailwindcss not applying styles in React Project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I'm trying to use tailwindcss in my React Project developed through Vite. But it's not working.
Let me explain the process step by step.

At first, I run following commands:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

Then, added following code to my `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

After that, added tailwind layers to `index.css` file.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And finally, run the following command:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch
```

But the issue is that the styles aren't generating at all through tailwind.
Also, my `package.json` also shows tailwind in devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
```

Here is the link to github repo: https://github.com/muhammadfuaad/my_react_app

Answer (score 0):

change from `content: ["./src/*.{html,js,jsx}"],` to `content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],` in your tailwind.config.js file.